# AWS Glue Error: The specified subnet does not have enough free addresses to satisfy the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

I have a AWS Glue job that gets the data from S3, transforms it and loads to multiple Redshift tables.

> **Glue Job Details:**
>  Type: Spark 
>  This job runs : A new script to be authored by you 
>  Worker type: Standard 
>   Maximum Capacity : 5
>
> **Connection Details:**
>  The Glue job uses *"Data catalog > connection"* to connect to Redshift
>  Connection type : JDBC
>
> **Sometimes the Glue job fails with below Error:**
>   *The specified subnet does not have enough free addresses to satisfy the request (Service:AmazonEc2, Status Code: 400, Error Code:
>   InsuffecientFreeAdressesInSubnet)*

**Is there a way to calculate the number of IP Addresses required by the Glue job based on above criteria or any other way to do it so that I can schedule the jobs in sequence**

Comment: I see cause to doubt `below Error` is copied&pasted flawlessly: please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Processing Units (DPUs) in Glue or workers decide the amount IPs you need. If you are using a subnet with not enough IPs, then select a small DPU count. The Subnet that you have added on your connection is the one that gets used. If you have another subnet in the same VPC, you can make use of that, as long as you can reach your redshift cluster from that subnet.

Comment: Thanks @Eman, That was helpful. Need a bit more clarification - 
If my Glue job has 5 DPU's and it loads to the target twice using "glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf" how many IP's will be used?

Comment: A single job writing twice will obviously use the same set of IPs. If you submit the job after sometime you will notice different IPs. I am not sure whether your question is aimed towards the degree of parallelism, i.e the number of connections that will be open on the database?